# Link preview plugin for Twitter Bootstrap for cakephp

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, preview

I want to use this plugin in cakephp: https://github.com/Ekito/bootstrap-linkpreview but I don't know how to integrate it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You've linked to something that's not a (CakePHP) plugin. It's also css/js files only - so the steps in Cake are basically 1) put somewhere in the webroot 2) point at it.

Comment: @AD7six thank you so much , but can you tell me how to point at it in the code ,i have a table link and i want preview link before submit . i try to do it but nothing work ; thanks again

Comment: try something (think about it) and if you have problems - ask a question (or edit this one).

Answer (score 0):

This might push you in the right direction:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files